# What is the most effective way to read the last line of a file in c++?

Tags: c++, text-files

im trying to store a large list of prime numbers in a text file and if I end my program i need to be able to read the line of the file to see where I left off. I dont know how to read the last line with out reading every line of the file first.

Comment: a text file is not efficient format to store sequential primes e.g., it even might be faster to [generate all 32-bit primes](http://cr.yp.to/primegen.html) than to read them from  a text file.

Comment: I would definately store the numbers in binary format, say with `__int64`, not with text. Seeking to the last binary number in a file would be a simple matter of jumping to file offset `((filesize / sizeof(__int64)) - 1) * sizeof(__int64)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know either. Just write the last value into a separate file, and read that value to know where to resume.

Comment: cant do that because it wont be kept if i run the file again

Comment: @user1767077 - whoops, typo; write the last value into a separate **file**.

Comment: @user1767077 Into another file, e.g. `last_prime.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You could use setg() to jump to the end of the file and do guesses how far a line is. If there's a newline between your point and the end of the file then you're in the next-to-last line and know what the last line is.

But Pete Beckers solution is a lot nicer, I'd go with that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the bytes of your numbers.

For example you have 5 number and you want to read last number.

1 integer is 4 byte. So you can move 4*4=16 Byte in file using fseek. After that you can read last line.

fseek (file , 16 , SEEK_SET);

SEEK_SET means begining of file.

Comment: The file is not binary (otherwise why to delimit the integers by newlines) therefore one integer is not strictly 4 bytes e.g., 1 is 1 byte, 100 is 3 bytes.

Comment: You can also use whereAmI=ftell(file) before fclose(file) and after open the file again fopen(file) and fseek(file, whereAmI, SEEK_SET)

Answer (score 1):

Seek to the very end of the file, and just read backwards till you find the newline character which means you have found the the start of the last line

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum length of line this will be easy.

Just go the the pointer that is the location of the end of file less this value.

Start reading lines from there and put them in a buffer. Clear buffer when the previous character was a new line

When you ran out of file the buffer will contain it.

If you do not know the maximum length you can always read the file backwards.